# Strange behaviour with python multiprocessing and neat-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I was working on a Tetris playing AI that uses [neat-python](https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python) and I ran into a really strange bug.

Here's a summary of what happens:

- Set population size to something large (>150)
- Start "training" (evolution) process
- Game crashes because of a piece somehow going out of bounds

I checked my tetromino collision function, and it's not the problem. I added a list attribute to my game object that stores every action executed (even if it fails) and dumped it and some other useful objects (current piece, "held" piece, game board, pieces placed onto board) and found some bizzare results:

```py
>>> actions = [...] # All executed actions, the last one is presumably failed
>>> len(actions)
92
>>> actions.count('hold')
87
>>> actions.count('down') # This gets execute only by the game object thread timer
5
>>> 87 + 5
92
>>> current.direction # The default direction for piece is 'up' and there's no 'rotate'
... # in executed actions
'right'
>>> [piece.direction for piece in unbag] # unbag here being a list containing every
... # single piece that was placed/locked/pasted to the game board
['up', 'down', 'up', 'right', 'left']
```

Looking at the snippet above, the only thing I could think of was maybe some game instances were "touching" when training as I was evaluating 48 at once. With that theory in mind, I added a new attribute to the game object, uuid. It gets set to `str(uuid4())` in `__init__` that way I could log it in the piece object:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self, board: np.array=None, network: FFN=None, render=False):

        self.uuid = str(uuid4())
```

and

```py
class Mino:
    def __init__(self, type_: str, pos: Tuple[int, int]=None) -> None:
        if type_ not in 'IJLOSTZ':
            raise ValueError(f'invalid tetromino type {repr(type_)}')
        self.type = type_
        if pos is None:
            pos = SPAWN_POSITIONS[type_]
        self.x: int = pos[0]
        self.y: int = pos[1]
        self.direction = 'up'
        self.id_log = set()
...
    def rotate(self) -> None:
        self._log_id()
        ...
...
    def move(self, board, dir_):
        self._log_id()
        ...
...
    def _log_id(self):
        stack = inspect.stack()
        caller_object = stack[2][0].f_locals['self']
        if isinstance(caller_object, Game):
            self.id_log.add(caller_object.uuid)
```

but checking out the results of that endeavor we get:

```py
>>> current.id_log
{'aa7980ed-c3a6-4ab6-8c41-0938e1b78eb1'}
>>> for p in unbag:
...     print(p.id_log)
...
{'aa7980ed-c3a6-4ab6-8c41-0938e1b78eb1'}
{'aa7980ed-c3a6-4ab6-8c41-0938e1b78eb1'}
{'aa7980ed-c3a6-4ab6-8c41-0938e1b78eb1'}
{'aa7980ed-c3a6-4ab6-8c41-0938e1b78eb1'}
{'aa7980ed-c3a6-4ab6-8c41-0938e1b78eb1'}
```

As you can see, the tetromino is reporting that it has been touch by `aa7980ed-c3a6-4ab6-8c41-0938e1b78eb1`, which means either my testing methodology is wrong or black magic is involved.

Would love to know what exactly is happening.

Code: https://github.com/yoursred/tetris-ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some much needed sleep, I think I have figured it out. The pieces only having the signature or uuid of the game object that it belongs to, while also showing signs of parallel execution means that the game object itself has to have something that is manipulating it in parallel, which it does. That thing is the `threading.Timer` game clock, which kinda makes sense. If you time it just right, it is impossible for the game clock to move a piece down while it is already being moved somewhere else (to be more exact after the collision check and before actually moving it), thus allowing it to go out of bounds if in a situation where it would just lock the piece normally.

With that in mind, I propose this solution:

- Add a new 'gravity' action to be executed only by the game clock
- Stop the game clock just before executing anything else (rotate, left, right...)
- Execute said action
- Restart the timer with the first instance waiting for however long the last one has left

And here is the solution in code:

```py
# custom timer class that can report time left
class MyTimer(threading.Timer):
    started_at = None
    def start(self):
        self.started_at = time.time()
        threading.Timer.start(self)
    def elapsed(self):
        return time.time() - self.started_at
    def remaining(self):
        if self.finished.is_set():
            return 0
        return self.interval - self.elapsed()
```

And in the `Game` class:

```py
...
    def timetick(self, dt=None):
        if not self.gameover:
            self.timer = MyTimer(self.tickdelay,
                                 self.timetick if dt is not None else dt)
            self.game_step('down')
            self.timer.start()
...
    def game_step(self, cmd='nop'):
        ...
        dt = self.timer.remaining()
        self.timer.cancel()
        ...
        self.timetick(dt)
...
```